# How to manage Y-axis on Chart.js?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I am using Chart.js and would like to manage my Y-axis. It should look like this:

[image]

Intervals should be 15 steps and it should always show the maximum value - 45 (even the data from X-axis is less).

I am trying this:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 45,
                stepSize: 15,
            }
        }]
    },
}
```

It doesn't work for me: the interval is not 15, but 2, and the maximum Y-axis value depends on X-axis data - if data is 30, then maximum Y-axis value is 30.

How could I fix that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your browser's dev tools, in the console it's likely you would see this error:

> Invalid scale configuration for scale: yAxes

At least that's what I see when trying to use your `options` object. This tells us that we've not written the `scales` property correctly.  Looking at the chart.js documentation, we see that `scales` is always an object, not an array of objects. Also based on your requirements it sounds like you would want to set `max` instead of `maxTicksLimit` which means you should write an options object like this:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: {
      display: true,
      max: 45,
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 15
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work for me.

First of all, I don't see the error message in my console. Also, I tried to use your code, but nothing had changed...

Help is still very needed and appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: perhaps some more fundamental issue is at play such as improper installation or configuration.  I think it'll be necessary for you to reproduce your issue with an online code editor, [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-lamarr-595hid), codepen, jsfiddle, etc. or provide a github repo link in order to help you further.